# for loop not working when passed inside a string as an argument to eval

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The following code when run as an individual command in shell script gives the expected result :

```
for x in This is good; do echo $x; done
```

**[OUTPUT]**

```
This
is
good
```

However when i pass it inside a string to Eval for some reason x is not being initialised

```
cmd = " for x in This is good; do echo $x ; done"
eval $cmd
```

**[OUTPUT]**

```
//Three blank lines
```

Why is x not being initialised ?

Comment: BTW, note that using `eval` in bash is generally a "code smell". It [introduces security vulnerabilities](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) when not used very carefully, and new versions of the language provide ways to accomplish most or all of its typical use cases [without needing it](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Comment: Also, `cmd = "some string"` isn't actually an assignment in bash -- it tries to run `cmd` with the first argument `=` and the second argument `some string`; to have an assignment proper, one cannot have spaces around the `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes to assign to `cmd` so `$x` isn't already consumed at assignment time.

Also, put double quotes around your argument to `eval` (the bugs it prevents are more subtle, and don't impact your current string, but when you do hit them they're serious).

```
cmd='for x in This is good; do echo "$x"; done'
eval "$cmd"
```

Note `echo "$x"` instead of `echo $x` -- see [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something different!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: Is there a way to keep cmd in double quotes and still have it working as expected ?

Comment: @kurokami, `"\$x"` -- adding a backslash before the `$` -- will work.

Comment: @kurokami, also, note that you can change quoting types within a string, so you can have most of the string in double quotes, but then just that one part in single quotes.

Comment: @kurokami, ...however, that gets complex quickly, which is part of why storing code in strings is an antipattern; the good-practice way to store code is in functions, which the shell itself can come up with a correctly-escaped textual representation of if you need to pass them around.